# "onload" in <body> tag of HTML and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know if "onload" is attribute of <body> tag of HTML. I saw this code snippet while I was going through a book (for learning Java Script).

```
<html>
    <body onload="alert('hi')";>
      ...
    </body>
</html>
```

I know that <body> tag is part of HTML specification. And for an HTML element we can have attributes. Going by this, does it mean onload is <body>'s attribute? Or is it part of JavaScript? How is this merger possible?

If so, does it also mean when HTML was initially developed, did the creator thought that there might be some event driven stuff to be applied (by some other language?).

Can anyone help me in understanding this? Till this point the book/s i have referred it didn't throw any light on what my doubt is, hence asking this question.

Comment: "If so, does it also mean when HTML was initially developed, did the creator thought that there might be some event driven stuff to be applied (by some other language?)." Initially, no, but the HTML spec has been revised many times (which is why we have HTML5). As javascript was developed, event hooks were added to the DOM api.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, makes sense. One small thing when you say DOM api, what exactly is that? I have heard about the DOM model (parsers), is that same what you are referring here? If can provide some pointers, would be great.

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways to attach event handlers to any HTML element is by giving it an attribute named `onEVENTNAME`. The value of such an attribute is a string of Javascript that will be executed when the event is triggered on the element. You've almost certainly seen things like

```
<button onclick="doSomething()">
```

This is the same kind of thing.

The HTML specification of [Global Attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes) says that `onload` (among many other `onXXX` attributes) can be used in any HTML element. There are also a number of `onXX` attributes that are specific to the [`<body>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-body-element).

The only thing special about the `<body>` element in this regard is that some of the event handlers are assigned to the `window` object. So your example is roughly equivalent to:

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert('hi');
};
```

Comment: To add on to this, since OP seems to be asking questions about the origin of this attribute as well: `onload` *is* part of the HTML specification: see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-body-element and https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handlers

Comment: It's part of HTML and DOM. JavaScript is only in the picture because it's the default language available for use in browsers. Actually, for many years, you could use VBScript in IE :).

Comment: @Barmar: So in strict context, onload is an attribute of the <body> element?

Comment: Of course. All `foo=bar` parts of HTML are attributes. What else would it be?

Answer (score 0):

The `onload` attribute fires when an object has been loaded.
`onload` is most often used within the `<body>` element to execute a script once a web page has completely loaded all content (including images, script files, CSS files, etc.).

The syntax is,

```
<element onload="script">
```

This below few html tags for supported like

```
<body>, <frame>, <img>, <link>, <script> and <style>
```

Example:

```
<img src="image.gif" onload="alert('image loaded')">
```

Thus the above code onload on an  element, Alert "Image loaded" immediately display after an image has been loaded.